# APEX: How to get Field Label Name using Field API?

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger

I am trying to get Field Label using the Field API. I have copied this code from Google but am not sure how to make use of it in order to achieve my requirement.

Thank you.

```
Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> mfields = Schema.OBJAPI.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = mfields.get(field).getDescribe();
fieldResult.getLabel()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is correct.

You just need to pass objectname in `OBJAPI` and field api name in `field`.

Something like this.

```
Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> mfields = Schema.Account.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = mfields.get('Primary_Program_Id__c').getDescribe();
System.debug(fieldResult.getLabel());
```

Output would be:

> 11:34:55.17 (25026221)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|DEBUG|Primary Program Id

Comment: Awesome that was quick and accurate. I tried and it worked. Great, thank you, Nagendra. :)